# C++: is the if() pointer check optimized?

Tags: c++, loops, compiler-optimization

The following code test the clock time of 2 setters's calls.  One checks for a null pointer, one doesn't.  Output of the program compiled -O3 flag gives the same times:

```
  0.000000 ticks (0.000000 secs)
  0.000000 ticks (0.000000 secs)
```

with -O0 flag, the timing differences is still tiny

```
  4250000.0000 ticks (4.25000 secs)
  4230000.0000 ticks (4.25000 secs)
```

is this being optimized by the compiler in a for loop?  If so, how should one test for a "real" world scenario on the efficiency difference of the two?

```
class B {};
class A
{
public:
      void set( int a ) { a_ = a; }
      int get() const { return a_; }
private:
      int a_;
};

class A1

public:
      A1() : b_(0) {}

      void set( int a ) { if( b_ ) a_ = a; }
      int get() const { return a_; }

private:
      int a_;
      B* b_;
}; 


int main()
{
      const int n=1000000000;
      clock_t t0, t1;

      A a;
      A1 a1;

      t0 = clock();
      for( int i=0; i < n; ++i ) 
            a.set( i );
      t1 = clock();
      printf( "%f ticks (%.6f secs)\n", (double) t1-t0, ((double) t1-t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

      t0 = clock();
      for( int i=0; i < n; ++i ) 
            a1.set( i );
      t1 = clock();
      printf( "%f ticks (%.6f secs)\n", (double) t1-t0, ((double) t1-t0) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC );

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler seems to optimize away the entire loop, because the program doesn't make any use of the values set in the loop. How about adding some code that makes use of the value, e.g. by printing it? (The printing would obviously not be included in the time measurements.)

Comment: If you look at the assembly, both loops are completed optimized away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking for a null pointer is almost certainly a one clockcycle operation.   On any modern processer, that'll be one two-billionth of a second.   I think that's beyond the resolution of the tick counter (which does milliseconds or microseconds, depending on the platform).

If you really want to know, look at the assembler code emitted, in the debugger.

Comment: OP is on the right track in looping a billion times, but `clock` has no subsecond precision and it all needs to be done more carefully. The check may consist of a comparison and a branch, at a fraction of a billionth of a second each, but they may be done simultaneously with other operations in hardware so the net time taken is zero.

Comment: The tick count is performed for all `n=1000000000` iterations. You don't need nanosecond resolution to measure differences in the total amount of time taken for this.

Comment: @jogojapan   Actually, you would.   If the null check takes 1 2-billionth of a second, and you do a billion loops, the time difference would not be captured by a single clock tick 50% of the time.

Comment: @Curt, yes, sure, you won't get perfect accuracy. You never do. But it's reasonable to expect a difference (and with `-O0` there is, although it would have to be discussed whether that difference is significant). Your answer seems to suggest that a) a null pointer check is performed in one clock cycle [which is not entirely accurate as it may actually take less than one clock cycle], and b) that it's impossible to get an approximation of the time taken by such operations.

Comment: @Curt,@jogojapan, thanks for the answers.  Make sense, but then how do you measure that a pointer check is 1 2-billionth of a sec?

Comment: @user2566773: Naively, by doing it 20 billion times. But the main problem still stands. You're using the wrong mental model, a sequential one. Every modern CPU executes multiple instructions at the same time, in particular when there are no data dependencies. This means that a null pointer check will take different amounts of time depending on what you will do with the pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The measurement results in the `-O3` case are 0, so clearly the compiler optimized away much more than merely the null-pointer check. It removed the loops entirely, and the reason is that the results generated in the loops are never used.

You do have `a.get();` and `a1.get();` in the code to retrieve the values generated in the loops, but, again, the results of these function calls are not involved in any side effects, so the compiler removes them.

If you replace these `get()` calls with a print statement *placed after the `clock()` call* (to ensure the IO is not included in the time measurement), you get different results (I've removed the actual values of `a` and `a1` from the output):

```
2540000.000000 ticks (2.540000 secs)
0.000000 ticks (0.000000 secs)
```

So the first loop now performs some real action, while the second one is still optimized out (Clang 3.3). The reason for this is probably that the setting of `a1._a` depends on a pointer which is initialized to `0` and then never changed in the loop. After inlining the function call to `a1.set()` into the main loop, the compiler is readily able to see that the assignment of `a1._a` will never happen.

---

(Note: As `a1._a` is never actually set, printing its value means printing the value of a variable that has never been initialized. Indeed I get a very random-looking output, and of course, strictly speaking, printing that value invokes undefined behaviour.)

Comment: In general, printing an output that could still be calculated at compile time doesn't guarantee the loop will survive optimisation. In this case the compiler might determine that only the last iteration has any lasting effect. It's better to make sure the loops do something that has some cumulative value-mutating affect (like totalling runtime-determined values). For runtime-values, it's often convenient to use something like `argc != 99 ? 0 : 1` - you know it'll always be 0 in your profiling usage, but the compiler can't know that.  Also, loop unrolling + inlining means results are doubtful.

Comment: Thanks both.  Also edited original post -- update the code to sum a's value and cout the sum at end of both loops.  Now, it seems to do something more sensible to do the comparison.  Still interested in knowing how one measure that an if pointer check is 1 2-billionth of a sec though...

Comment: @user2566773 Regarding your question: You need to ask Curt. Regarding your edit of the question: You have effectively incorporated my answer in the question, changing the meaning of the question. I don't consider that appropriate. Regarding Tony D's remark: I never said printing the output gives any sort of guarantee. But as a matter of fact, with the given code and the compiler I described, it worked.

Comment: @jogojapan, on editing the original question -- I guess that's true.  Sorry about the misuse.  First time to use this site.  I thought it would be nice to see actually see it in the code to reflect the solution.  I guess best is put back the question in the original form so other people looking at it later would be more meaningful.